# Shipping Table rates Weight vs Destination Ranges

Tags: magento2, shipping, magento-2.0, table-rates

I have this CSV

[image]

I have imported it into `Store->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Methods->Table Rates successfully`

But when I buy an item weighing 60 kg and the shipping address is Sevilla, shows me the price of the first row (11,00 €) instead of the second (25,00 €)

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In country if I put ES instead of ESP, then works fine.